# Regex Wildcard for Array Search

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, search, wildcard

I have a json array that I currently search through by flipping a boolean flag:

```
for (var c=0; c<json.archives.length; c++) {
if ((json.archives[c].archive_num.toLowerCase().indexOf(query)>-1)){
inSearch = true;
} }
```

And I have been trying to create a wildcard regex search by using a special character '*' but I haven't been able to loop through the array with my wildcard.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is when query = '199*', replace the '*' with /[\w]/ and essentially search for 1990,1991,1992,1993,1994 + ... + 199a,199b, etc.

All my attempts turn literal and I end up searching '199/[\w]/'.

Any ideas on how to create a regex wildcard to search an array?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code where you do this replacement? Also what are you changing? I'm assuming that archive_num is the full string.

Comment: the attempt that turns everything literal was this:  query = query.replace('*', /[\w]/);

Comment: in JS you should not use quotes '*' but /\*/ for the search string and the replace string should be quoted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write something like this:

```
var query = '199*';
var queryPattern = query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w');
var queryRegex = new RegExp(queryPattern, 'i');
```

Next, to check each word:

```
if(json.archives[c].archive_num.match(queryRegex))
```

Notes:

- Consider using `?` instead of `*`, `*` usually stands for many letters, not one.
- Note that we have to escape the backslash so it will create a valid string literal. The string `'\w'` is the same as the string `w` - the escape is ignored in this case.
- You don't need delimiters (`/.../`) when creating a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object from a string.
- `[\w]` is the same as `\w`. Yeah, minor one.
- You can avoid partial matching by using the pattern:

  ```
  var queryPattern = '\\b' query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w') + '\\b';
  ```

  Or, similarly:

  ```
  var queryPattern = '^' query.replace(/\*/g, '\\w') + '$';
  ```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks for the tips as well, they will definitely help me out in the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
var qre = query.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "\\$&") // escape special chars so they dont mess up the regex
               .replace("\\*", "\\w");      // replace the now escaped * with '\w'

qre = new RegExp(qre, "i"); // create a regex object from the built string
if(json.archives[c].archive_num.match(qre)){
    //...
}
```