# Can I use wildcards when searching an array of strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of strings:

```
x = ["banana","apple","orange"]
```

is there a built in shortcut for performing wildcard searches?

ie., maybe

```
x.indexOf("*na*") //returns index of a string containing the substring na
```

Comment: Why not just search for `na` or use a regex... You could also augment String and write your own.

Comment: I would use a regex, possibly this may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333246/regex-wildcard-for-array-search

Comment: Thanks, the regexp suggestion helped. Maybe put that up as an answer "there's no shortcut, but using a regex is easy", with a code sample snippet

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Expanding on Pim's answer, the correct way to do it (without jQuery) would be this:

```
Array.prototype.find = function(match) {
    return this.filter(function(item){
        return typeof item == 'string' && item.indexOf(match) > -1;
    });
}
```

But really, unless you're using this functionality in multiple places, you can just use the existing `filter` method:

```
var result = x.filter(function(item){
    return typeof item == 'string' && item.indexOf("na") > -1;            
});
```

The RegExp version is similar, but I think it will create a little bit more overhead:

```
Array.prototype.findReg = function(match) {
    var reg = new RegExp(match);

    return this.filter(function(item){
        return typeof item == 'string' && item.match(reg);
    });
}
```

It does provide the flexibility to allow you to specify a valid RegExp string, though.

```
x.findReg('a'); // returns all three
x.findReg("a$"); // returns only "banana" since it's looking for 'a' at the end of the string.
```

Comment: Great answer. But this solution will not work for every string. Consider the case of Urls where we can have '?' and '/' in the strings. Code will throw an error for those cases.

Comment: Shortened to a one-liner: `x.filter(s => typeof s == 'string' && s.indexOf("ne") > -1);`

Answer (score 5):

Extending on @Shmiddty's answer, here are useful JavaScript ideas:

- Extend Array with a new method: `Array.prototype.method = function(arg) { return result; }`
- Filter arrays using: `Array.filter(function(e) { return true|false; })`
- Apply formula to elements in an array: `Array.map(function(e) { return formula(e); })`
- Use regular expressions: either `/.*na.*/` or `new Regex('.*na.*')`
- Use regular expressions to match: `let result = regex.test(input);`
- Use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggergate a result after running a function on every element of an array

i.e. I prefer the input argument to be a regex, so, it gives you either:

- A short but universal pattern matching input,

  - e.g. contains, starts with, ends width, as well as more sophisticated matches
- The ability to specify an input pattern as a string

**SOLUTION 1: filter, test, map and indexOf**

```js
Array.prototype.find = function(regex) {
  const arr = this;
  const matches = arr.filter( function(e) { return regex.test(e); } );
  return matches.map(function(e) { return arr.indexOf(e); } );
};
let x = [ "banana", "apple", "orange" ];
console.log(x.find(/na/)); // Contains 'na'? Outputs: [0]
console.log(x.find(/a/)); // Contains 'a'? Outputs: [0,1,2]
console.log(x.find(/^a/)); // Starts with 'a'? Outputs: [1]
console.log(x.find(/e$/)); // Ends with 'e'? Outputs: [1,2]
console.log(x.find(/pear/)); // Contains 'pear'? Outputs: []
```

**SOLUTION 2: reduce, test**

```js
Array.prototype.find = function(regex) {
  return this.reduce(function (acc, curr, index, arr) {
    if (regex.test(curr)) { acc.push(index); }
    return acc;
  }, [ ]);
}
let x = [ "banana", "apple", "orange" ];
console.log(x.find(/na/)); // Contains 'na'? Outputs: [0]
console.log(x.find(/a/)); // Contains 'a'? Outputs: [0,1,2]
console.log(x.find(/^a/)); // Starts with 'a'? Outputs: [1]
console.log(x.find(/e$/)); // Ends with 'e'? Outputs: [1,2]
console.log(x.find(/pear/)); // Contains 'pear'? Outputs: []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the array prototype to find matches in an array

```
Array.prototype.find = function(match) {
    var matches = [];
    $.each(this, function(index, str) {
        if(str.indexOf(match) !== -1) {
            matches.push(index);
        }
    });
    return matches;
}
```

You can then call find on your array like so

```
// returns [0,3]
["banana","apple","orange", "testna"].find('na');
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex can do this in javascript

```
var searchin = item.toLowerCase();
var str = columnId;
str = str.replace(/[*]/g, ".*").toLowerCase().trim();
return new RegExp("^"+ str + "$").test(searchin);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everything else that has been said, you can do this:

```
var x = ["banana", "apple", "orange"];
var y = [];
for (var i in x) {
    if (x[i].indexOf('na') > -1) {
        y.push(i);
    }
}
```

Results: y = [0]