# JavaScript - filter with wildcard (*)

Tags: javascript

I want to filter over a collection of items with an eventual wildcard.

Let's say, I have the following items:

```
const items = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Melon']
```

I now want to filter with the following strings:

```
e
```

Expected output: None

```
*e
```

Expected output: Apple

```
*e*
```

Expected output: Apple, Melon

```
ana
```

Expected output: None

```
*ana
```

Expected output: Banana

```
*an
```

Expected output: none

```
*an*
```

Expected output: Banana

I hope you get my intention. Is there any smart way to do it with regex or standard JS functions / libraries? I couldn't find something so far.

Comment: Reference Link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695594/can-i-use-wildcards-when-searching-an-array-of-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can construct a regular expression by replacing `*`s with `.*` to match any characters, and surround the wildcard string with `^` and `$` (to match the beginning and the end):

```js
const items = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Melon']

const filterBy = str => items.filter(
  item => new RegExp('^' + str.replace(/\*/g, '.*') + '$').test(item)
);
console.log(filterBy('e'));
console.log(filterBy('*e'));
console.log(filterBy('*e*'));
console.log(filterBy('ana'));
console.log(filterBy('*ana'));
console.log(filterBy('*an'));
console.log(filterBy('*an*'));
```

Note that if the wildcard string ever has any other characters with a special meaning in a regular expression, you'll have to [escape them first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex).