# JavaScript how to replace using wildcards

Tags: javascript, replace, wildcard

I have a string with potentially random characters in it. I wanting to replace all instances of a section with wildcard support. Example:

```
var input = 'abcdef acbdef acdbef';

input = coolFunction(input, 'a*b', '_');
```

```
// I want to replace every charachter between an a and the next closest b with _'s
//Output should be '__cdef ___def ____ef'
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Do you have anything against using a regex?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Similar question that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143451/javascript-filter-with-wildcard

Comment: but second part of question - the output e.g. `____ef` (change all occurrence to _ is not trivial for me as pure regexp solution

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let input = 'abcdef acbdef acdbef';
let wild = 'a*b';

let re = new RegExp(wild.replace(/\?/,'.').replace(/\*/,'.*?'),'g');
let output = input.replace(re, c => '_'.repeat(c.length)); 

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Check your output and then check the requested output. They want an underscore for each letter they substitute. So three underscores in the second example and four in the third.